# Go net.Dial overwriting existing connections

Tags: go, tcp, ip, goroutine

I am writing an application to manage connections between multiple devices, but the network connection interface seems to be overwritten when new connections are started, even in a new goroutine.

The main application creates the devices in a slice, and calls the following at launch (the communication channels are stored in the same structure for easy future reference):

```
for _, device := range devices {
        fmt.Printf("Starting device at %v\n", device.ipAddress)
        go device.run(device.outboundChannel, device.inboundChannel)
        success := <-device.outboundChannel
        if success.section == 0 && success.value == true {
            fmt.Printf("Device at %v started successfully!\n", device.ipAddress)
        }
    }
```

Internally, each routine runs the following:

```
func (a *ani22) run(outComms chan<- aniCommand, inComms <-chan aniCommand) {
    initErr := a.init()
    if initErr != nil {
        outComms <- aniCommand{3, 0, false, false, initErr.Error()}
    }
    outComms <- aniCommand{0, 0, true, true, "Connected!"}
    fmt.Printf("Device at %v now monitoring!\n", a.ipAddress)
    for {
        // Application loop happens here
    }
}


func (a *ani22) init() error {
    if a.connection != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Cannot connect to %v as connection already esablished!\n", a.ipAddress))
    }
    if a.ipAddress == "" {
        return errors.New("No IP Address specified!")
    }
    timeout := 5 * time.Second
    fmt.Printf("Dialling IP %v\n", a.ipAddress)
    dialErr := errors.New("")
    a.connection, dialErr = net.DialTimeout("tcp", a.ipAddress, timeout)
    if dialErr != nil {
        return dialErr
    }
    return nil
}
```

When running with a single device in the slice, it works without issue, but when any additional devices are added it blocks after one successful connection, almost like the connection is being overwritten for the next device, despite it being in a separate goroutine.

Comment: Difficult to help with the limited code provided (please aim for a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). However, you probably want an `else` after the `if success.section...` line to handle errors (the go routine should also `return` after sending the error). If that does not help please include more code (the output would also be useful).

Answer (score -1):

TLDR - I didn't check *all* of my race conditions properly.

It looks as though I was running into an error due to how I instantiated the array of devices.

The array is generated from a CSV file that is imported (boilerplate omitted for clarity). The original code works as such:

```
type ani22 struct {
ipAddress       string
connection      net.Conn
chan1Led        bool
chan2Led        bool
inboundChannel  chan aniCommand
outboundChannel chan aniCommand
}

func import () ([]ani22, map[int]ani22Channel, error) {
var aniList []ani22 // Blank array to hold devices

deviceMap := make(map[int]ani22Channel)

for line := range lines {
    var tempAni ani22 // Make a temporary device, then fill in the details
    tempAni.ipAddress = lines[line][0] + ":2202"
    chan1Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(lines[line][1])
    tempChannel := deviceMap[chan1Id]
    if tempChannel.ipAddress != "" {
        continue
    } else {
        tempChannel.ipAddress = tempAni.ipAddress
        tempChannel.port = 1
        deviceMap[chan1Id] = tempChannel
    }
    chan2Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(lines[line][2])
    tempChannel = deviceMap[chan2Id]
    if tempChannel.ipAddress != "" {
        continue
    } else {
        tempChannel.ipAddress = tempAni.ipAddress
        tempChannel.port = 2
        deviceMap[chan2Id] = tempChannel
    }
    tempAni.outboundChannel = make(chan aniCommand)
    tempAni.inboundChannel = make(chan aniCommand)
    aniList = append(aniList, tempAni)
}
return aniList, deviceMap, nil
}
```

This code does not activate the net.Conn item in the type, that is handled in the a.init() function called when the goroutine is spun off:

```
func (a *ani22) init() error {
if a.connection != nil {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Cannot connect to %v as connection already esablished!\n", a.ipAddress))
}
if a.ipAddress == "" {
    return errors.New("No IP Address specified!")
}
timeout := 5 * time.Second
fmt.Printf("Dialling IP %v\n", a.ipAddress)
dialErr := errors.New("")
a.connection, dialErr = net.DialTimeout("tcp", a.ipAddress, timeout)
if dialErr != nil {
    return dialErr
}
return nil
}
```

It appears as though the net.Conn object/interface is being default allocated when the item is appended onto the array. The new method that seems to have fixed this issue:

```
func import () ([]ani22, map[int]ani22Channel, error) {
var aniList []ani22
deviceMap := make(map[int]ani22Channel)

for line := range lines {
    var tempAni ani22
    tempAni.ipAddress = lines[line][0] + ":2202"
    chan1Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(lines[line][1])
    tempChannel := deviceMap[chan1Id]
    if tempChannel.ipAddress != "" {
        continue
    } else {
        tempChannel.ipAddress = tempAni.ipAddress
        tempChannel.port = 1
        deviceMap[chan1Id] = tempChannel
    }
    chan2Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(lines[line][2])
    tempChannel = deviceMap[chan2Id]
    if tempChannel.ipAddress != "" {
        continue
    } else {
        tempChannel.ipAddress = tempAni.ipAddress
        tempChannel.port = 2
        deviceMap[chan2Id] = tempChannel
    }
    tempAni.outboundChannel = make(chan aniCommand)
    tempAni.inboundChannel = make(chan aniCommand)
// Additional code relocated from main function, starting connection and routine before returning the array
    fmt.Printf("Starting device at %v\n", tempAni.ipAddress)
    go tempAni.run(tempAni.outboundChannel, tempAni.inboundChannel)
    success := <-tempAni.outboundChannel
    if success.section == 0 && success.value == true {
        fmt.Printf("Device at %v started successfully!\n", tempAni.ipAddress)
    }
    aniList = append(aniList, tempAni)
}
return aniList, deviceMap, nil
}
```

I think that by ensuring the connection is live before moving it, we ensure that it's unique, rather than letting the compiler decide to deal with an "unused" variable.

Comment: You are still not handling error conditions (you print "started successfully" if there is no error but continue on whether there is an error or not). I suspect that your real issue was that you are using `deviceMap := make(map[int]ani22Channel)` instead of `deviceMap := make(map[int]*ani22Channel)`  (see [this demo](https://go.dev/play/p/CYs3UNkIMKD))